# How to test Input with React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test an `input` value of `Search` component via React Testing Library.

Search component receives two props: `handleChange` and `input value`: `title`.

My goal is to write the test so that initially the input value is empty and when user types  something, test can validate that listening to event value was correct, but it always gets the initial value.

I'm trying to clear the input before typing but it doesn't work.

Error is:

```
 Expected the element to have value:
                       // indicates as empty string which I expect
                    
    Received:
      test            // it is still the default value: `test`, UserEvent.clear didn't clear
```

Here are the two test first checking if input initially was empty, which works fine and 2nd to listen to the input.

```
import { fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import Search from "../Search";
import { render } from "../../../test-utils/test-utils";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

const mockedOnChange = jest.fn();

describe("input should be filled with title", () => {
  test("input should be empty initially", async () => {
    render(<Search title="" onChangeHadler={mockedOnChange} />);
    const input = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: /search/i });
    expect(input).toHaveValue("");
  });
   // renderComponent wrapps the `Search` component
  const renderComponent = (searchInputValue: string) => {
    const view = render(
      <Search title={searchInputValue} onChangeHadler={mockedOnChange} />
    );
    return view;
  };

  test("input should update by typed text", async () => {
    renderComponent("test");
    const input = await screen.findByRole("textbox", { name: /search/i });
    await waitFor(() => expect(input).toHaveValue("test"));
    userEvent.clear(input);
    expect(input).toHaveValue(""); // error appears here indicating that value was not cleared

    // userEvent.type(input, "su"); 
    // await waitFor(() => expect(input).toHaveValue("su"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your tested component is a controlled component : it receives (props) its value from the parent component, with a function reference which notifies the parent that the user changed the input value. Typically this function will update the parent state, which is passed down to the child component, and used as the input value.

In your test you only render the child component, and you mock the callback function. So you cannot expect the input value to change when triggering user interactions in your test. You can only test that the `title` props is used as value for the input, and that the callback function (which is mocked in your test) is correctly called when you trigger user interactions. But you cannot test a "full scenario" without rendering the parent component.

```
test("input value is the title props", async () => {
    renderComponent("test");
    const input = await screen.findByRole("textbox", { name: /search/i });
    await waitFor(() => expect(input).toHaveValue("test"));
});

test("callback function is called on user interactions", async () => {
    renderComponent("test");
    const input = await screen.findByRole("textbox", { name: /search/i });
    userEvent.type(input, "new value");
    expect(mockedOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith("new value");
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually I am learning testing and it makes a lot of sense. Thanks for detailed explanation. Does it mean that I can test the full scenario in the parent component?

Comment: even though it makes sense,what you say, this doesn't work either

Comment: This is not to be copy paste as-is. You may need to wrap with await waitFor(...). But you got the idea.

Comment: ...and yes, you could test the full scenario by testing the parent component. Though keep in mind that a proper unit test of the child is still relevant, specially if the child component is to be used in another context, with a different parent component (not likely, but still)

Answer (score 0):

As @FlorianMotteau mentioned, if you want to test a *controlled* component (a component with props to get and update its value) on a *sequence* of events (pointer input, keyboard input, etc.), you should test the ancestor component that controls its value, the controlling component. If the controlling component does not exist or is too complex, you may create a fake one for testing purpose, like this:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { ControlledComponent } from './ControlledComponent'

const ControllingComponent = ({
  defaultValue,
  mockOnChange,
  ...rest
} => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);
  mockOnChange.mockImplementation(v => setValue(v));
  return (
    <ControlledComponent value={value} onChange={mockOnChange} {...rest} />
  );
};

test('should call onChange on keyboard input', async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  const defaultValue = '';
  const mockOnChange = jest.fn();
  render(
    <ControllingComponent
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      mockOnChange={mockOnChange}
    />,
  );
  await user.keyboard('abc');
  await waitFor(() => expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3));
  await waitFor(() => expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'a'));
  await waitFor(() => expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, 'ab'));
  await waitFor(() => expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(3, 'abc'));
});
```